# Unity 2D code repeating in phone but not trouble in pc

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make an game 2D in Unity. My game looks different on the phone. I would the gameobject come to the scene episodic. When I test it on the computer, there is not trouble. But when I test on the phone, the process is repeating.

Code :

```
for(kacxgiti = 0; kacxgiti < 91; kacxgiti++){
        karbayv = karbay.transform.position;
    if(kacxgiti < 90){
    karbay.transform.position = new Vector3(karbayv.x - 0.1f, karbayv.y, karbayv.z);
    kacxgiti = kacxgiti + 1;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }else{
    kamyongel();
    }
        }
```

Full Code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

public class karhareket : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject karbay;
    Vector3 karbayv;
    int kacxgiti;

    public static int kamyongeli, kamyongidi;
    public GameObject kamyon;
    Vector3 kamyonv, kamyonvv;
    int kamyonxgiti;
    int kamyoncikari;

    public Button subebtn;
    public Text guntext;
    int guni, gunfonti, gunbuyuti, kardurduri;

    public Sprite[] musteris;

    int musterigeli, musterixgel, mustericikari;
    public GameObject musteri;
    Vector3 musteriv, musterivv;

    public Text paratext;

    string gecisid;
    InterstitialAd gecisreklam;
    int ilkgunyazii;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        ilkgunyazii = 1;

        gecisid = "ca-app-pub-6761789303172472/5658205887";
        this.gecisreklam = new InterstitialAd(gecisid);
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        this.gecisreklam.LoadAd(request);
        this.gecisreklam.OnAdClosed += reklamkapatinca;
        this.gecisreklam.OnAdFailedToLoad += reklamkapatinca;

        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("para")){
            paratext.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("para") + "$";
        }else{
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("para", 100);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            paratext.text = "100$";
        }

        kamyongeli = 1;
        kamyoncikari = 0;
        kardurduri = 0;

        musterigeli = 1;

        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("mustericikar") == 1){
            ilkgunyazii = 0;
            guntext.text = "";
            musteri.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = musteris[PlayerPrefs.GetInt("musteriid")];
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("musteriid");
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("mustericikar");
            kamyon.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            musterigeli = 0;
            kamyongeli = 0;
            kardurduri = 1;
            guntext.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            musterigidivergari();
        }

        while(kamyongidi == 1 || PlayerPrefs.GetInt("kamyoncikar") == 1){
            int musterid = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, 20);
            musteri.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = musteris[musterid];
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("musteriid", musterid);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            ilkgunyazii = 0;
            PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("kamyoncikar");
            kamyongeli = 0;
            kardurduri = 1;
            kamyongidivergari();
            guntext.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            //gun ve karakter ilerleme olmasın
            break;
        }

        if(kardurduri == 0){
            kamyongeli = 0;
            karbayv = karbay.transform.position;
            //InvokeRepeating("pozisyonayarla", 0, 0.05f);

            for(kacxgiti = 0; kacxgiti < 91; kacxgiti++){
                karbayv = karbay.transform.position;
                if(kacxgiti < 90){
                    karbay.transform.position = new Vector3(karbayv.x - 0.1f, karbayv.y, karbayv.z);
                    karbayv = new Vector3(karbayv.x - 0.1f, karbayv.y, karbayv.z);
                    kacxgiti = kacxgiti + 1;
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
                }else{
                    kamyongelivergari();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }else{
            karbay.transform.position = new Vector3(-4, -1, 0);
        }

        while(kamyongeli == 1){
            InvokeRepeating("kamyongelsin", 0, 0.03f);
            break;
        }

        subebtn.onClick.AddListener(subetik);

        if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("gun")){
            guni = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("gun");
        }else{
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("gun", 1);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            guni = 1;
        }

        if(ilkgunyazii == 1){

            gunfonti = 20;
            gunbuyuti = 1;
            guntext.text = "Day " + guni.ToString();
            InvokeRepeating("guntextayarla", 0, 0.02f);

        }

    }

    void guntextayarla(){
        if(gunbuyuti == 0){
            guntext.fontSize = gunfonti;
            gunfonti--;
        }else if(gunbuyuti == 1){
            guntext.fontSize = gunfonti;
            gunfonti++;
            if(gunfonti == 61){
                gunbuyuti = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void musterigelsin(){
        musteriv = musteri.transform.position;
        if(musterixgel < 145){
            musteri.transform.position = new Vector3(musteriv.x - 0.1f, musteriv.y, musteriv.z);
            musterixgel++;
        }else{
            musterigeli = 0;
            SceneManager.LoadScene("malsat");
        }
    }

    void musterigitsin(){
    musterivv = musteri.transform.position;
    if(mustericikari < 575){
        musteri.transform.position = new Vector3(musterivv.x - 0.1f, musterivv.y, musterivv.z);
        mustericikari++;
        if(mustericikari == 165){
            gunbittiyaziayarla();
        }
    }
    
    }

    void kamyongelivergari(){
        //CancelInvoke("pozisyonayarla");
        kamyongeli = 1;
        //kardurduri = 1;
        InvokeRepeating("kamyongelsin", 0, 0.05f);
    }

    void reklamgoster(){
        if(gecisreklam.IsLoaded()){
            gecisreklam.Show();
        }else{
            reklamkapatincaa();
        }
    }

    public void reklamkapatinca(object sender, EventArgs args){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("manav");
    }

    public void reklamkapatincaa(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("manav");
    }

    void gunbittextayarla(){
        if(gunbuyuti == 0){
            guntext.fontSize = gunfonti;
            gunfonti--;
        }else if(gunbuyuti == 1){
            guntext.fontSize = gunfonti;
            gunfonti++;
            if(gunfonti == 41){
                gunbuyuti = 0;
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("gun", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("gun") + 1);
                PlayerPrefs.Save();
                reklamgoster();
                CancelInvoke("gunbittextayarla");
            }
        }
    }

    void gunbittiyaziayarla(){
        guntext.text = "Day " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("gun") + " Finished";
        guntext.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        guntext.text = "Day " + PlayerPrefs.GetInt("gun") + " Finished";
        gunfonti = 20;
        gunbuyuti = 1;
        InvokeRepeating("gunbittextayarla", 0, 0.02f);
    }

    void subetik(){
        SceneManager.LoadScene("subeler");
    }

    void pozisyonayarla(){
        karbayv = karbay.transform.position;
        if(kacxgiti < 90){
            karbay.transform.position = new Vector3(karbayv.x - 0.1f, karbayv.y, karbayv.z);
            kacxgiti++;
        }else{
            kamyongelivergari();
        }
    }

    void kamyongelsin(){
        kamyonv = kamyon.transform.position;
        if(kamyonxgiti < 125){
            kamyon.transform.position = new Vector3(kamyonv.x - 0.1f, kamyonv.y, kamyonv.z);
            kamyonxgiti++;
        }else{
            kamyongeli = 0;
            SceneManager.LoadScene("malal");
            CancelInvoke("kamyongelsin");
        }
    }

    void kamyongitsin(){
        kamyongidi = 0;
        kamyonvv = kamyon.transform.position;
        if(kamyoncikari < 300){
            kamyon.transform.position = new Vector3(kamyonvv.x - 0.1f, kamyonvv.y, kamyonvv.z);
            kamyoncikari++;
            if(kamyoncikari == 150){
                Debug.Log("geldi");
                musterigelivergari();
            }
        }else{
            CancelInvoke("kamyongitsin");
        }

    }

    void musterigelivergari(){
        InvokeRepeating("musterigelsin", 0, 0.03f);
    }

    void musterigidivergari(){
        musteri.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, -1.9f, 0f);
        InvokeRepeating("musterigitsin", 0, 0.05f);
    }

    void kamyongidivergari(){
        kamyon.transform.position = new Vector3(0f, -3f, kamyon.transform.position.z);
        InvokeRepeating("kamyongitsin", 0, 0.05f);
    }

    //kamyongidi 1 olunca kamyonu gönder

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        /*if(kamyongeli == 1){
            InvokeRepeating("kamyongelsin", 0, 0.05f);
        }*/

        /*if(kamyongidi == 1 || PlayerPrefs.GetInt("kamyoncikar") == 1){
            kamyongeli = 0;
            kamyongidivergari();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("kamyoncikar", 0);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            //kamyongidi = 0;
        }else if(kamyongeli == 1){
            InvokeRepeating("kamyongelsin", 0, 0.05f);
            kamyongeli = 0;
        }*/

    }
}
```

In pc :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IaOMyP4bzOopaQCjBtOBV-KBYBflIB_f/view?usp=drivesdk

In phone :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IcPNvg7OjCerzFKc8M12LrO8B-BKyWUC/view?usp=drivesdk

How I can resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you post the full function of your code and not just the for loop? Are these images `Images` or `Sprites` you are using in these videos?

Comment: I think due to the else part the process is repeating I might be wrong, but the loop is repeating until all the loop values are run. can you comment in the code what is 91 in for loop ?

Comment: something seems to overwrite `kacxgiti` in the meantime so it always jumps between multiple values ... Are you sure the routine is running only once at a time?

Comment: @TEEBQNE gameobject image

Comment: @derHugo yes. I added full code.

Comment: @Suraj Bhandarkar when is 91 another object come to scene

Comment: kacxgiti = kacxgiti + 1; can you remove this line and try to build for the phone?

Comment: @SurajBhandarkar ok. I try.

Comment: @SurajBhandarkar The some problem continue.

Comment: You can't use `yield` inside a `void` so this code **shouldn't even compile** to begin with ... Also what are these `while` loops good for if anyway you always immediately `break` in the first iteration ?

Comment: Just a question, why didn't you use animation instead?